# How to get drawable from a button?

Tags: android

Since on button, we can use android:drawableLeft to set the drawable on the left of a button. Is there way to get this drawable programmatically?

```
<Button android:id="@+id/detail_refresh_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/refresh" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/progress"
/>
```

Is there any way to get the drawable "progress" in Java code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you want `Button.getCompoundDrawables()[0]`

Comment: Ok, thank you. It worked. I missed that when I checked the API.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

You can see that

```
myButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable,Drawable,Drawable,Drawable)
```

Should give you what your looking for.

Order: Left, top, right, and bottom

Comment: Thank you. I checked this method but forget to check getCompoundDrawables(). The problem is resolved now

Answer (score 0):

If the view is button,

```
button.getBackground().setLevel(x);
imageView.getDrawable().setLevel(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Doc Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawables())

```java
Button.getCompoundDrawables()[index]
```

where `index` can be 0, 1, 2, 3 for `drawableLeft`, `drawableTop`, `drawableRight`, `drawableBottom` respectively.